# How to lock Oracle DB table row in Java for REST API even after the API response is returned

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jdbc, optimistic-locking

I want to lock a single record in a table until it's not finished updating.

The problem is it's a web application and I am providing a REST API to send the data for edit. I have tried using `@Lock` annotation and `query.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)`.

I have also tried the `SELECT * from TBALE_NAME tn where tn.id =:id for update`,  this also only works as long as the transaction is active.

These above things work and lock the record as long as the transaction is not completed , i.e. as long as the API does not return back the data. Once the data is sent to UI for API, the lock is released.

#### My controller API code

```
@GetMapping("/getData/{id}")
public Object getData(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
return myService.getData(id)
}
```

As soon as this above API returns the data, the lock is released if I add one. I want to keep it locked until the same user has updated the table row.

#### MyService method code

```
public Object getData(Long id){
 repositoty.findById(id);
}
```

My repository using the JPA implementation:

```
Object findById(Long id);
```

#### What is required

When a user goes to the edit page in UI and called the API /getData/id, I want to block that record for everyone. So if there is any other user who tries to edit that record, they will get some kind of exception that this record is already in use.

I cannot create a column in the table to save the info on the row that the user is using it.

Comment: Then make a second table maintaining edited records? Pessimistic locking is transaction based, so you are out of luck there. Also with java persistence on top, you might want to keep things simple & verifiable: who is keeping a "lock", since when.

Comment: @JoopEggen. I also suggested the same to my client , but he doesn't want to add any table or column in DB for this locking.

Comment: There is the java side too: the persistency layer / cache. Maybe serializing the edited objects. But that has nothing to do with any kind of practices I participated in. Putting edits in some queue would probably also be unacceptable. Good luck